# HTTP request with generic class in Java

Tags: java, http, generics, web, generic-handler

I have a generic class:

```
BaseResponseDTO<T>
{
    T payload;
}
```

I'm making a REST call which returns this object:

```
String url = "http://REST-CALL-LINK";
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
BaseResponseDTO<UserDTO> requestMap = new BaseResponseDTO<UserDTO>();
HttpEntity<BaseResponseDTO<UserDTO>> reqEntity = new HttpEntity<BaseResponseDTO<UserDTO>>(requestMap, headers);
BaseResponseDTO<UserDTO> response = new BaseResponseDTO<UserDTO>(new UserDTO());
ResponseEntity<BaseResponseDTO<UserDTO>> responseUnifiedDTO = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, reqEntity, response.getClass());
UserDTO user = responseUnifiedDTO.getBody().getPayload();
```

This piece of code gives me the error:

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from ResponseEntity<capture#2-of ? extends BaseResponseDTO> to ResponseEntity<BaseResponseDTO<UserDTO>>
```